# Link should become clickable only after javascript loads

Tags: javascript, html

I have a "login" link that opens a login page (login.php) within a lightbox-style iframe.

Generally it works fine, however if a viewer's internet connection is very slow, there's a possibility of them clicking the login link before the lightbox javascript has loaded. Which then causes login.php to load in the window itself instead of the lightbox iframe, which is a problem.

So, is it possible to delay the click-ability of that link, until after the specific .js file has loaded? i.e. when page first loads, "login" is not click-able, then after the javascript loads, "login" becomes an active link.

Or - What is the best solution to this problem?

Thanks!
~Daniel

Comment: Without any code of the page, we cannot help you. Please post the full code.

Comment: Why is it a problem for the login page to open in the window itself instead of in the lightbox? Consider taking a [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) approach: make sure that at least the _basics_ of your site work with JS disabled.

Comment: leave empty and set the href or src with your javascript with onload=...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can have something like a lazy loader.

```
<a href="#" data-href="login.php" class="lazy">log in</a>
```

Now, the elements with the class `lazy` will be having a dummy non working link. And after the window loads, we will replace the right link, so that it works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.lazy').removeClass('lazy').attr('href', $(this).data('href'));
});
```

Also, if you feel it might be an issue, you can hide the login button and show it once the document loads, like this:

```
<a id="login" ... style="display: none;">Login</a>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#login').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Document.Ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

> A function to execute after the DOM is ready.

Code Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var login = $("<a href='login.php' >Login</a>");
    $('#elementName').append(login);
});
```

Or check if something exists  `if (typeof something != 'undefined')` before doing anything.

Comment: Great response, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without code it's hard to say.  However, my best guess would be that it's waiting for the document to load before it bootstraps the lightbox you are using.  This is the right thing for that lightbox to do.

As suggested by a comment in your post by @Matt Ball, you'd need to have a non-javavascript option that is replaced on page load with the prettier javascript option.

Answer (score 0):

One simple info regarding scripts. 
Always put your scripts under your body tag for fast loading. Not in head tag if you want fast response.

Answer (score 0):

@Praveen Kumar's solution works, but here's a simpler way that doesn't involve having to really "lazy-load" the link:

HTML:

```
<a href="login.php" class="lazy">log in</a>
```

JS (add this into your lightbox script, after the lightbox is loaded):

```
$('.lazy').removeClass('lazy');
```

Or without jQuery (simpligying example):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.lazy')[0].className='';
```

CSS:

```
.lazy { -moz-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; }
```